# Repeating values in SSRS Cascading parameter

Tags: sql-server-2008, t-sql, reporting-services, parameters, repeat

I have 4 parameters in my report and my requirement is user should be able to select all values from the parameter list.

So I have created cascading parameters but one of it shows multiple values corresponding to other parameters

eg:
   A
   A
   A
   B
   B
   B
   B
   C
   C

Ideal: A
       B
       C

I tried by unchecking allow multiple values in Parameter properties.

Param3-> taking values from Dataset3(Col3)

```
       Main Dataset:

            SELECT Col1, Col2, Start_Date, End_Date, Col3
            FROM  Table
            Start_Date IS NULL OR
  Start_Date >= @StartDate) 
    AND (End_Date <= @EndDate) 
    AND (Col3 IN (@Param3))

        Dataset 1:

        SELECT DISTINCT Col1
        FROM  Table

        Dataset 2:

        SELECT DISTINCT Col2
        FROM            Table
        WHERE        (Col1IN (@Param1))
        ORDER BY Col2

        Dataset 3:

        SELECT DISTINCT Col1, Col2, Col3
        FROM  Table
        WHERE       
        (Col1 IN (@Param1)) 
        AND (Col2 IN (@Param2))
```

Any inputs/ideas/suggestions if I can get only Distinct values in my parameter list instead of repeating values?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem seems Dataset 3 is returning repeated values for `Col3`since `DISTINCT` clause is applied across every column you select in the query.

This is a valid return of your dataset 3

```
Col1 Col2 Col3
 A    A    E
 B    D    E
 C    C    E
```

> Note every row is different but Col3 has repeated values.

To get different values in your parameter you can create an additional dataset to populate `Parameter3`.

```
SELECT DISTINCT Col3
FROM  Table
WHERE       
(Col1 IN (@Param1)) 
AND (Col2 IN (@Param2))
```

Let me know if this helps you.